# can go_router open page in new tab?

Tags: flutter

I am using go_router for a app . i want to open a route called `CheckAuth` in new tab

```
final router = GoRouter(
      debugLogDiagnostics: true,     
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/',
          builder: (context, state) {
            return child: (const Dashboard());
          },
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: 'CheckAuth',
          path: '/CheckAuth',
          builder: (context, state) => const CheckAuth(),
        ),            
     ],     
    );
       );
  }
return MaterialApp.router(
      routeInformationProvider: router.routeInformationProvider,
      routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: appTheme(context),
      builder: (context, myWidget) {
        myWidget = EasyLoading.init()(context, myWidget);
        myWidget = ref.responsiveWrapperSetting(context, myWidget);
        return myWidget;
      },
    );
```

I use `context.pushNamed('CheckAuth');`  method to navigate. but i want it to open in new tab. how can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with a new tab? In a web browser?

Comment: @quoci yes .in flutter web

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
context.pushNamed('/CheckAuth');
```

I think this should work.